# How do I enable Full Disk Access for a macOS app being built and debugged in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an app that accesses system files. When I built and archive the app, I'm able to drag that app into the Settings > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access and grant it full permissions

However, when the app is built using Xcode, how do I enable this? I don't know where Xcode stores a temporary binary that is running within Xcode. If I don't have the path, I can't grant it permission.

How do I enable Full Disk Access to an app that is being built and archived within Xcode and has not been archived yet

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know where Xcode stores a temporary binary that is running within Xcode

In the Project Navigator look for the Products group and click on its disclosure triangle to see the files within. There is an entry for every product - compiled app, library etc. - the project produces (these entries are red if not built yet). Right-click on your app and select Show in Finder. HTH

Comment: This is a correct answer, but in my case (not the OP) it didn't work because dragging the built app from Xcode's "derived data" build directory into "System Preferences / Privacy / Full Disk Access " list -did nothing at all. It refuses to take my App!!! what now? maybe the App itself should signify it wants this? Is there a special Info.plist entry for that?

Comment: @MottiShneor – There is nothing an app needs to do, this is an operation the user does through System Preferences. A quick test  (in Big Sur) shows it works with both signed sandboxed apps and ad-hoc signed (by Xcode) non-sandboxed apps. You should open a new question, explain what you've tried and what goes wrong, and someone will hopefully be able to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

When you're developing the app and building from Xcode you can set the App Sandbox entitlement to "NO", so that your app can access files outside of the bundle.

Keep in mind that if you'll want to publish the app to the Mac App Store you'll need to put that parameter back to "YES" and eventually ask the user to grant disk access permissions.

[image]

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox