# Process.run Returns 'The file “<command>” doesn’t exist.'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to write a small app to start/stop and display data from a command line "app" someone else wrote. The command executable is installed in '/usr/local/bin'.  It outputs status text data to standardOutput while running.  I can execute this "command" from the Terminal.app without issue.  From swiftUI code I can successfully execute "built-in" commands like ls.  However, when (in swiftUI code) I attempt to execute Process.run WITH the new command it throws the exception 'The file “” doesn’t exist.'

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Here's a code snip:

```
  // NOTE: "installedCommand" is just a placeholder for the actual command.
  let task = Process()
  let connection = Pipe()

  let exeUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/installedCommand")
  //let exeUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/ls") <--works fine

  task.executableURL = exeUrl
  task.standardOutput = connection

  do
  {
      try task.run()
  }
  catch
  {
      print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return
  }
```

Comment: if you are using Xcode for the project then you can see the executable under the folder `Products`. Right click to show in Finder and now you have the location of the executable. Now use this location in your code. Or you could copy the file to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The "installedCommand" is a 3rd party program that was installed in /usr/local/bin by a package installer.  My xcode project is attempting to run it.  I don't have access to the original project.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Instead of setting `task.executableURL` can you type `task.arguments   = ["-c", command]` where command is a String that you would like to execute. Let the command string be the same as the command you executed on the terminal

Comment: I'm confused.  What command should I be 'run'ing that will take the -c argument?

Comment: Oh <duh> you mean sh -- Pretty sneaky idea.  It works from Terminal.  Will try in code.

Comment: Well, progress.  Now I get '/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/installedCommand: Operation not permitted'.  Again, I can execute '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/installedCommand' successfully in Terminal.  Any ideas?  Does my app need special permissions or something?

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. try this `task.arguments = ["-c", "who"]` This would tell the user that is being used. Check the output to see if it matches the user you are using

Comment: Yes, your app needs permission to access the disk. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856496/how-do-i-enable-full-disk-access-for-a-macos-app-being-built-and-debugged-in-xco. The question contain some details about archiving the app then using granting the app full disk access. Give it a try. Alternatively if it was a command line app you wouldn't have this trouble.

Comment: To execute a command ls, you should do `task.arguments = ["-c", "ls"]`

Comment: Actually, I found the fix for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544566/operation-not-permitted-when-executing-killall-with-swift).  I just had to update the "App Sandbox" to "NO" in the .entitlements plist in the project.  It's all working now!  Thanks @user1046037 for your help.